# Realtek HD Audio Manager doesn't detect microphone

Tags: windows-8, audio, microphone, audio-recording, realtek-hd-audio

For some reason, a couple weeks ago, Realtek HD Audio Manager stopped giving me the "Microphone" option when I plug in an audio device.

This is what it shows when I plug a microphone in:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3TVJD.jpg]

It doesn't show a "Microphone" option anymore, like it used to.

Comment: Are you sure the microphone still works?

Comment: Yes, I tested it with 2 different micophones